# Why would you need to check for if an 2D array is above float(inf) or below float(-inf)

Tags: python

I am currently looking at some code and trying to decipher what the authors are trying to do and how. I am stuck on this section:

```
#List comprehension checking if any single array in 
# 2D filtered array is > Artifact or < -Artifact

data.streams[GCaMP].filtered = 
    [
        x 
        for x in data.streams[GCaMP].filtered 
        if not np.any(x > ARTIFACT) or np.any(x < -ARTIFACT)
    ]
```

They define `ARTIFACT` as `float("inf")`. What I am confused about is if the lower- and upperbound is infinitely small and infinitely large respectively, why would any number have to be checked against these two upper- or lowerbounds? All number would always be larger than an infinitely small lowerbound and always smaller than an infinitely large upperbound. So for me, the limits set by `float("inf")` and `float("-inf")` seems useless.

What is it that I am missing with this code?

Comment: the code has the capability to filter artifacts that you turn off by setting artifacts to inf

Comment: @PranavHosangadi no. If artifacts = inf the feature is off (it doesnt filter anything). If you set it to something else you turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

That code removes items from `data.streams[GCaMP].filtered` if any of those items contain an element that is outside the range `[-ARTIFACT, ARTIFACT]`.

You're right -- with `ARTIFACT` as infinity, it has no effect. Check if the code allows you to change `ARTIFACT` to something else (I suspect it does)